# what is the regex for url's with parameters?

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting

if i have a `<form action='./search' method='get'>`
 with `<input type='text' name='keyword' value='this is the search term' />`inside

 after submitting the form, it leads me to `/search?keyword=this%20is%20the%search%20term`

what regex should i use to capture that form of url and rewrite it to
 `/search-this_is_the_search_term`

Answer (score 1):

First [urldecode](https://www.php.net/urldecode) the search string and then replace the spaces with underscores. E.g.:

```
$str = "this%20is%20the%search%20term";
$decoded = urldecode($str);
$final = str_replace(' ', '_', $decoded);
```

You can do the same with a regular expression using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) only more reliably as you may need to remove multiple consecutive spaces:

```
$str = "this%20is%20the%search%20term";
$decoded = urldecode($str);
$final = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $decoded);
```